# Intellij Error running GlassFish: Address localhost:8080 is already in use

Tags: java, jsf, intellij-idea, port, glassfish-4.1

Maybe it's a stupid question but, I can't solve it.

I'm trying to run GlassFish server in Intellij IDEA 2017.1 and I get:

- Error running GlassFish: Address localhost:8080 is already in use

I already checked in cmd if any other process is using port 8080 and there is no other process. When I start Intellij IDEA then one process appears in cmd and if I kill this process then Intellij IDEA shutdown. I think that maybe some instance of GlassFish starts when I run Intellij IDEA but I have no idea why and how to solve it... besides it's possible that is any other issue.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: How are you checking in cmd if other process is using port 8080? I use _netstat -aon | findstr "8080"_

Comment: I also used netstat -aon | findstr "8080",..